# Slideshow: Fade in and Fade out on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am creating a slideshow using JQuery. Slideshow works with the code below:

```
     function playSlideshow() {

            timer = setInterval(function () {

            thumbnails.children[currentNum].className = '';

                currentNum++;
                if (currentNum > data.files.length - 1) {
                    currentNum = 0;
                    console.log(currentNum);
                }

                var currentImage = data.files[currentNum];
                target.src = currentImage;

                thumbnails.children[currentNum].className = 'current';
               //playSlideshow();
            }, 3000);                
        }
```

However, I got an error (currentImage.fadeIn is not a function) once I inserted the lines of codes below:

```
    function playSlideshow() {

        timer = setInterval(function () {

            thumbnails.children[currentNum].className = '';

            $('#main>img').fadeOut('slow');

            currentNum++;
            if (currentNum > data.files.length - 1) {
                currentNum = 0;
            }

            var currentImage = data.files[currentNum];
          //var image = data.files[currentNum].clone(true);
            $('#main>img').prepend(currentImage.fadeIn('slow'));
            target.src = currentImage;

            thumbnails.children[currentNum].className = 'current';
           //playSlideshow();
        }, 3000);                
    }
```

I got the 'files' array from a JSON file using Ajax.
Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is `currentImage` set to a `File` object? What is `data.files`?

Comment: files is an array in a JSON file which I got using Ajax. data is a parameter of a function in Ajax.

Comment: What's the type of the array? Does it hold `HTMLElement`s, or jQuery html elements, or `Image`s, or something else?

Comment: The array is paths of the images, so I created HTML elements (<img>) in the function of Ajax and store the data into the img attribute (src)

Comment: Are they jQuery <img> elements? i.e. did you call `$(element)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#main>img').prepend(currentImage).fadeIn('slow');
```

Fade on the jQuery object, not the array object.

`currentImage.fadeIn is not a function` is telling you that either currentImage is not a jQuery object, or fadeIn doesn't exist in the jQuery namespace.

Comment: Thank you. The error is gone, but the project is working as a normal slideshow without fading in.